# Latent Profile Analysis using clickstream data

Tags: clustering, structural-equation-modeling, latent-class

I have some clickstream data about students' use of a learning management system. This data includes variables such as number of clicks on Content X, number of visits to Page Y, etc. I want to derive the profiles of students based on the way they used the system.

I am very new to Latent Profile Analysis. I wonder if I can apply it using such continuous variables.

Comment: Not sure whether it makes a difference for your analysis (it may well), but count variables are not "continuous".

Comment: Latent Profile Analysis is actually for continuous data, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_class_model#Related_methods

Comment: This may be of interest, though I'm not sure whether there is software: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9574.2004.00125.x

Comment: @ChristianHennig then I wonder what is the correct category for the click data. Thanks!

Comment: It's count data.